# Why is Google Chrome displaying strange letters when I press comma in some sites?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

In some sites, including Google Plus, when I press the comma in the text input it displays strange characters instead of putting in the comma. This only happens in Chrome. I tried it in IE and Firefox. I think it has something to do with the fact that the site appears to use a div with javascript instead of using an actual textbox.

I am not sure what is going on. It looks like some kind of debugging symbols or something. Here is what is displayed when this happens.

Chrome version 12.0.742.122

[image]

Comment: do you have any extensions? what do your about:flags say?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be related with [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jdfpnijdiejbhebabijgoibmnngiblhk). Or maybe [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/abcekjakjehkpheoaadhkjfcdodpjbgk). Try disabling them.

These extensions allow you to select links without using the mouse.

Answer (score 2):

I'd check with your extensions and `about:flags`. Try disabling them all and re-enabling them one by one.